# Setup postgresql for django in windows

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm learning django and here I'm trying to change the database from the default sqlite3 to postgresql. I've searched all over the internet(google,bing,duckduckgo,..) but no results.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'websitedb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'teamarrow',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}`
```

Changed the database in settings.py,
Installed postgresql,installed psycopg2 for windows from [here](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/),
Created a new database in pgADMINIII.

In command prompt `python manage.py runserver`. This is the error:

```
 ` Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__ini
t__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__ini
t__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21
, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", li
ne 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line
 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.p
y", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", l
ine 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", l
ine 297, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py"
, line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line
 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 24
2, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 10
8, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\website\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresq
l_psycopg2\base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module n
amed psycopg2
```

Please debug where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the PostgreSQL adapter (psycopg2) installed:

```
Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

You should download the correct version and install it first:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

**Update**: Because of the incorrect formatting of the question I couldn't see that you already downloaded it. Did you take the comments in the "Virtual Environment Installation Notes" into account? You should not double click the installer exe when you are using a virtualenv. Instead, you should use [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installing-and-using-setuptools) or [distribute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3) to install the package into your virtualenv. See http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

JUST install

```
pip install pyscopg2
```

under your folder

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that pycog2 is not installed.

To install pycog2 type this in your command prompt:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: I do not see any added value by this answer, as it is exactly similar solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56715905/3157428). Please always check if others have not posted same solution previously to avoid redundancy.